# Diffrential equation question, cannot find constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The rate of cooling a body is given by $\frac{dθ}{dt}=kθ$, where k is a constant. If $θ$ is 60°C when $t$ is 2 minutes and 50°C when $t$ is 5 minutes, determine the time taken for $θ$ to fall to 40°C, correct to the nearest second. Answer: 8m 40s

1st I solved the diffrential equation:

$$\frac{dθ}{dt}=kθ$$
$$\frac{dθ}{θ}=kdt$$

Integrated both sides...
$$\int\frac{dθ}{θ}=\int{kdt}$$
$$ln({θ})=kt+c$$
$$θ=e^{kt+c}$$

Let $e^c=A$
$$θ=Ae^{kt}$$

I'm able to get this far, but I can't determine what the values of $A$ and $k$ are from the information given, I've been looking at this for hours now and this is the best I can do...if someone could help me out or give me a hint at least I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting the given values into the equations and then solve for A and theta you will have two unknowns and two equations.

Comment: I'll give that a try thanks.